# Postfix server seems not to act properly on smtp response codes, it keeps retrying for 5 days after 5.1.1 permanent errors

Tags: postfix, compliance

Recently we've got into trouble with a big receiving MX system (got temporarily blacklisted). After some discussion with the postmaster who was extremely helpful, he showed me his log entries with badto(us) and 550 5.1.1 permanent error response codes to my initial delivery try. But our postfix (v3.4.23, almost standard install) server kept repeating delayed retries for 5 days. It made me believe that our server is not acting properly on received response codes. i.e. reporting the permanent error directly instead of insisting for 5 days first.

This leaves me with three questions.

1. Is postfix retrying for 5 days expected behavior on 5.1.1 permanent errors?
2. Can i configure postfix to stop and not retry on 5.1.1 permanent errors?
3. If yes, what is the mechanism to manipulate this behavior ?

I've been looking in the postfix documentation, but can't find useful guidance (my ignorance ?). As i was searching for this question online i did not get any hits on this topic so if anyone has some suggestion for good information on this it would be very welcome.

Comment: As presented, this is question is not a good fit here and will probably be closed. Its reasonable to ask if this is expected with the default configuration, and/or to provide your configuration  and ask if you have changed something which would cause this behaviour.

Comment: I agree with symcbean and welcome, Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.

Comment: Actually.. The problem is a bit different than i thought. I'll have to rewrite the whole thing. Maybe it's better to delete and start over? The thing is: Although the receiving MX is reporting a 550 5.1.1 our server interprets a dsn=4.1.1, status=SOFTBOUNCE and keeps on trying. I'll incude log and config.. Now sleep (6 AM) Thanx for making me look better at the issue.

Comment: Because this question needs significant correction anyway, I'd just rewrite the entire thing with the question you've now narrowed down on. Editing is encouraged, and making this question a good one that can be answered is good for you and good for this site.